# The advantage/disadvantages in using timthumb.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, timthumb

I recently installed a new Wordpress theme, and it uses timthumb.php to render thumbnail images.

I found the CPU in my server becomes very busy. I use htop and see there are many timthumb.php processes poping up.

However, I don't really want to turn off timthumb.php for two reasons. First, it does render better thumbnails if I want them to be in a fixed width/height. Secondly, some of the external images need some kind of proxy to be shown and timthumb.php serves this purpose.

This is my first time to know about timthumb, should I keep using it? Or should I find some other tools to do the same things? I also turned on WP Super Cache plugin, it does help a bit, but the CPU is still quite busy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP speaking, TimThumb is a dead horse:

- [Official WordPress Theme Guidelines](http://make.wordpress.org/themes/guidelines/wordpress-version-specific-features/changes-wp-3-3/): **Themes MUST NOT use TimThumb.**
- [ThemeForest Guidelines](http://support.envato.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/472/85/wordpress-theme-submission-requirements): **Use of Timthumb is not allowed.**

Either chose another theme or research for an alternative on [Make WordPress](http://make.wordpress.org/themes/), [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) and [ThemeForest forums](http://themeforest.net/old_search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=timthumb&type=forums&type_id=topic:25).